# Do Python lists have columns?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I am learning how to create dictionaries in python.

Look specifically at this code:

**for row in apps_data[1:]:
            c_rating = row[10]**

```
opened_file = open('AppleStore.csv')
from csv import reader
read_file = reader(opened_file)
apps_data = list(read_file)
content_ratings = {'4+': 0, '9+': 0, '12+': 0, '17+': 0}

for row in apps_data[1:]:
    c_rating = row[10]
    if c_rating in content_ratings:
        content_ratings[c_rating] += 1

print(content_ratings)
```

Why can I not use **for c_rating in apps_data[1:,10]:** instead?

```
opened_file = open('AppleStore.csv')
from csv import reader
read_file = reader(opened_file)
apps_data = list(read_file)
content_ratings = {'4+': 0, '9+': 0, '12+': 0, '17+': 0}

for c_rating in apps_data[1:,10]:
    if c_rating in content_ratings:
        content_ratings[c_rating] += 1

print(content_ratings)
```

Comment: Because Python lists don't support indexing like that, you're thinking of numpy multidimensional arrays (see e.g. https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html). Lists are a simpler data structure, they don't "know" anything about their content.

Comment: I have not gotten to numpy yet, is that similar to Pandas? Also, what do you mean by "...they don't 'know' anything about their content"? Does this mean that lists do not have columns?

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it. Lists of lists don't have columns, no - the outer list has references only to the inner lists, not to *their* elements.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't support that kind of indexing.

I suggest you try pandas. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv')

for c_rating in df['rating']:
    if c_rating in content_ratings:
        content_ratings[c_rating] += 1
```

Pandas will read your CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame, which is like a two-dimensional array on steroids.

The first row will automatically be used as column headers. So, you don't need to skip the first row in your code.

Also, instead of relaying that your c_rating is in 10th column, you can refer to the column using the column's header from the first line of your CSV file.

Comment: So, would you say that the way I am using lists is an uncommon way to perform the action? In other words, Pandas is a preferred method? I am learning through an online course, and they may teach me Pandas in the near future.

Comment: No that it's uncommon; it's just that you can't say `apps_data[1:,10]`. If you don't want to use Pandas, just do it the longer way.